# How to copy a string from textbox in iOS XCUITests

Tags: ios, swift, xctest

I wanted to Verify whether Cut/Copy/Paste options are disabled or not in the app

I tried

```
    networkPage?.textUrlInput?.tap()
    networkPage?.textUrlInput?.typeText("hello")
    networkPage?.textUrlInput?.doubleTap()
    networkPage?.texUrlInput?.buttons["Select"].tap()
```

The Select/Select all options is getting disabled instantly, so my test case was failing

Comment: u can set userInterface.false it will make that view user can't operate...

Comment: Can you please be more elaborate.?
My question was how to verify that Cut/copy/paste options are not displayed when i double tap on my textfield

Comment: what you did to disable your text? Have you written any code with MenuController or Pastboard? Also you can add following code (say paste option) in your viewcontroller.m - (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    if (action == @selector(paste:))
        return NO;
}

Comment: Hi Gagan_iOS through swizzling the below method and sending No as response
CanPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender

Comment: Yes gagan i followed the same method that you specified

Comment: you are sending NO for all the operations so Select is getting disabled. You have to check in if-else condition for  copy, cut & paste and return NO, for other operation return YES

Comment: Yes when i do manually select is coming, even through automation i was able to select and select all but they are disappearing instantly

Comment: did you get your solution or still messing?

Comment: Still messing gagan

Comment: show me your code for - (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action

Comment: How to click on that Select option from XCUITests

Comment: Gagan let me know how can i assert for that select option, since we are blocking the whole menu as mentioned instead of copy/paste/cut

Comment: please show me your code for - (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action

Comment: - (BOOL) canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {    
    UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
        [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible = NO;
        if([self canResignFirstResponder]){
            [self resignFirstResponder];
        }
        return NO;
    }

Comment: ok.. now write in this way      -(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    if (action == @selector(paste:))
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else if (action == @selector(copy:))
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else if (action == @selector(cut:))
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}     there will be select/selectall option but not copy/cut

Comment: That is fine gagan,
I wanted a way that i can click on select/select all option through xcuitests